# Creating a design system file from library

Tags: sketch-app

We created a design system. We have over 800 symbols. We want this to use as the linked library for our clients. We also want to include a design file, quick start guide that has all those symbols linked and included. Is there a bulk way to include linked symbols in a sketch document?

If not, is there another way this might work

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this isn't directly related to Graphic Design but an implementation of a distribution system.

Comment: I would suggest diving into the [Sketch's plugin developer page](http://developer.sketchapp.com/).